# Xamarin - Exception while loading assemblies Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writing a program using Xamarin Forms, at some stage my project has started to require the `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract` dll and cannot seem to find it.

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

My question is when is this file needed in Xamarin forms, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only delete the project references the library

Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract and recompile.

all ok